# Not displaying the table in web page using flask

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask

Hi I am using flask to create a web app in python. 
In my profile.html page in template direcotiry I have profile.html as shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>App</title>

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../static/js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/getAcademic.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

      <div class="jumbotron">
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

In the app.py,

```
@app.route('/getDetails')
def getDetails():
    try:
        #get data from mysql database and convert to a json and return

        return json.dumps(academic_dict)

    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('error.html', error=str(e))
```

The returned json object is as follows,

[image]

In my js file,

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getDetails',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {
            var div = $('<table>')
                .attr('class', 'list-group')
                .append($('<tr>')
                    .attr('class', 'list-group-item active')
                    .append($('<td>')
                        .attr('class', 'list-group-item-text'),
                        $('<td>')
                        .attr('class', 'list-group-item-text')));


            var wishObj = JSON.parse(res);
            var wish = '';

            $.each(wishObj,function(index, value){
                wish = $(table).clone();
                $(wish).find('td').text(value.Title);
                $(wish).find('td').text(value.Data);
                $('.jumbotron').append(wish);
            });
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

json is converted and returned correctly but the data is not displaying in the profile.html page. I checked the console and it is displaying the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined` in the .js file.

I want to display a table with the data returned as the json object but the table is not displaying when the profile.html page is loading. Please help me with this.

Comment: please share profile.html, although the error is pretty clear: `wish = $(table).clone();`; here, `table` is indeed not defined.

Comment: @AArias I edited the question with profile.html

Answer (score 0):

You've got one simple mistake (but don't worry, that happens to everyone...) on the line `wish = $(table).clone();` – you use `table` to reference `<table>` you saved in variable `div` .

Either replace `$(table)` with `$(div)` there or (I would suggest this solution for readability) rename `var div = $('<table>')` in the beginning to `var table = ...`

*(Sorry for reviving such an old post, but I'm on badge hunt `:]`)*

Oh, and one more point: please don't use screenshots of code, but the code itself (even just shortened) for us to test your problem and our solution:

```
[{'Title': 'Name', 'Data': 'john mark'},
{'Title': 'Faculty', 'Data': 'cs'}]`
```